# jQuery's dollar syntax vs dollar sign JavaScript "convention"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've read [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/and-in-javascript-2037515) that for JavaScript there's a "convention" that the `$` function be defined as a shortcut for `document.getElementById`, so I've defined the following function in a `<script>`,

```js
function $(x) { return document.getElementById(x); }
```

so I could write `$('main')` instead of `document.getElementById('main')`, for instance.

Soon after, when I started looking into jQuery, [I found that jQuery uses the syntax `$(selector).action()` extensively](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp).

However, the two solutions don't seem to work nicely together.

Are indeed the two mutually exclusive? As in, if I use jQuery, I can't use the `$` function above, and if I use the latter I can't use jQuery?

Comment: `$` is more frequently used as an alias for `querySelector`, rather than `getElementById` - `getElementById` only works if the elements you're selecting have specific IDs, which often isn't the case. Browser consoles support this too.

Comment: If you use jquery you won't *want* to use getElById

Comment: @freedomn-m, you mean that I can do more easily with jQuery?

Comment: I mean: jquery has so much more flexibility than a simple get by ID.   In most cases you don't even want your elements to have IDs.  Of course, as mentioned above, the *relatively new* querySelector / querySelectorAll could be used rather than get el by id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to return control of `$`. Then, to use jQuery, use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('#main')
```

You can also assign the returned value of `noConflict` to an object, and use it just like `$`:

```js
var a = jQuery.noConflict();
a('#main')
```